# vue loop through array inside object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to loop an array inside object. Here's my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-river-viwom?file=/src/components/accordion.vue). What I want to achieve is, for example, I click the `How to make pancake?` button, and it redirects me to another page where it shows an (bootstrap) [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) full of questions from this js file

```
export const questionList = [
  {
    slug: "how-to-make-pancake",
    title: "How to make pancake?",
    questions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "First question?",
        answer: "First Answer"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        question: "Second question?",
        answer: "blablablabla"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    slug: "how-to-make-pancake2",
    title: "How to make pancake2?",
    questions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "First question?",
        answer: "First Answer"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        question: "Second question?",
        answer: "blablablabla"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    slug: "how-to-make-pancake3",
    title: "How to make pancake3?",
    questions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "First question?",
        answer: "First Answer"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        question: "Second question?",
        answer: "blablablabla"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

in the accordion.vue, I think this line of code doesn't work

```
data() {
    return {
      questionslist: questionList.questions,
    };
  }
```

My question is, how to access the questions array in every object in the `questionList`? I'm sorry if it's kinda confusing and my language is not good. Thank you so much.

Comment: Since 'questionList' is an array, you cannot access 'questions' as 'questionList.questions'.  You would need 'questionList[arrayIndex].questions'.  One of the existing answers may do what you want, but just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flat():

```
data() {
  return {
    questionsList: questionList.map(q => q.questions).flat();
  };
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error 
`You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     data () {
|         return {
>             questionsList: questionList.map(q => q.questions).flat();
|         }
|     }
`
what kind of loader do i need?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to flatten all of the `questions` arrays into a single array? You can do it like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    questionsList: questionList.reduce((res, obj) => {
      return [...res, ...obj.questions];
    }, [])
  };
}
```